# Editing UITableViewCells in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Regarding a UITableView in EDIT mode:

1. I'd like to intercept touches or clicks on the green or red UITableViewCellEditingStyle icons that display when editing a UITableView.
2. I'd also like to manually mark a specific row for deletion the way that clicking on the red icon automatically does.

IE: if a particular row is associated with a red (DELETE) icon, in my app, clicking the row or clicking the red icon should perform the same behavior - mark or unmark it for deletion. Likewise, if a particular row is associated with a green (INSERT) icon, I want clicking the row or clicking the green icon to perform the same behavior. Obviously, the green icon doesn't mark a row for insertion but Apple "Contacts" catches that touch and drills down into a child controller -- which would be just fine.

Clicking a row triggers

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but what does clicking the UITableViewCellEditingStyle icon trigger?

And ... is there a way to programmatically mark a row for deletion (cause the big red DELETE image to appear in the same manner that clicking the red DELETE icon does).

Thanks,

-Luther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW11) appears to be my answer for #1.

Several people have suggested #2 is a bad option since it is not standard behavior. Agreed.